# Accessing control client name and not ID in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net, onclick, client-side

I want to fire a server-side [ASP.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET) button click event in JavaScript. I checked the page source and the `button`'s `onclick` in client side is:

```
WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("ctl00$LoginInfo1$btnliOK", "", true, "", "", false, false));
```

But I have to replace `ctl00$LoginInfo1$btnliOK` with something like `<%= btnliOK.ClientName %>`. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can get it using the Control.UniqueID Property

```
btnliOK.UniqueID
```

[`UniqueID`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.uniqueid(v=vs.110).aspx) gives the on page rendered **name**
[`ClientID`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid(v=vs.110).aspx) gives the on page rendered **id**
[`ID`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.id(v=vs.110).aspx) give's the id that you can use **on code behind**

Comment: Just wanted to say thank you for this - this solved about six hours of frustration with the jQuery validation plugin!

Comment: Thank you so much, I have been doing '.ClientID.Replace("_", "$")' for ages. Which was terrible is anything was named with a _ inside.