# Span Id changes in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html

I have a span in a `.master` page that uses `runat="server".` Server-side, c# code adds to the innerHtml of this span. The span is `id="tickerfade"`; however, when it is rendered on the page the id is changed to `id=ctl00_tickerfade`. why does this happen and how can I stop it?

Comment: if you want to use this span in `javascript` you can write `$('<%= tickerfade.ClientID %>).click(....)'

Comment: You can also get the rendered id using the `<%=ControlID.ClientID%>` See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5763557/accessing-control-client-name-and-not-id-in-asp-net

Comment: @harry180 perfect. That worked like a charm. Submit as an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: @steventnorris pls change/add tag to javascript and for future add good tags to your questions :) I've made answer for you to accept;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's happend because `Control` which is rendered on `server` side has autogenerated Client side Id.

If you'll use asp.net out of box control (`<asp:Label />`and so on) you can set `ClientIdMode` to `Static`

if you want to use this span in javascript you can write

`$('<%= tickerfade.ClientID %>).click(....)`

Answer (score 4):

You can set the control's [`ClientIdMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx) to [`Static`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientidmode.aspx).

> The ClientID value is set to the value of the ID property. If the
>   control is a naming container, the control is used as the top of the
>   hierarchy of naming containers for any controls that it contains.

Have a look at following link for further informations on ASP.NET Web Server Control Identification:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1d04y8ss.aspx

If the real problem is how to find the correct id on clientside, you can use the `ClientId` property.

Comment: When I set the clientidmode i get the error "Error parsing attribute 'clientidmode': Type 'SPTasks.mainpage' does not have a public property named 'clientidmode'." due to lack of support below .net 4.0. Our server is running 3.0. Any work arounds for 3.0?

Comment: ClientIdMode work in 3.0 and up version but only on `server` `controls` like `<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" />` @aristos if u don't know pls stop made it up;)

Comment: @steventnorris: If you need the id on clientside, you can use the `ClientId` property.