# Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object required in form

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, jscript

I have this **html code**:

```
<td align="center">
    <asp:Button ID="btnPesquisar" runat="server" Text="Pesquisar" Width="150px" CssClass="manu_btn" OnClientClick="return validaParamsEstatisticaTopSearch();" ToolTip="Prima para efectuar a pesquisa">
    </asp:Button>
</td>
<td style="font-size: 10px;">
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTopSearch" runat="server" Width="250px" Font-Size="10px" AutoPostBack="true" ToolTip="Escolha o tipo de pesquisa">
    </asp:DropDownList>
</td>
```

and my function:

```
function validaParamsEstatisticaTopSearch(){

var dT=document.getElementById("ddlTopSearch").value;
var dL=document.getElementById("ddlLingua").value;
var tT=document.getElementById("txtNTop");

var tdI=document.getElementById("txtDiaI");
var tmI=document.getElementById("txtMesI");
var taI=document.getElementById("txtAnoI");

var tdF=document.getElementById("txtDiaF");
var tmF=document.getElementById("txtMesF");
var taF=document.getElementById("txtAnoF");


if( dT=="*" )
{ 
    alert("Por favor escolha uma das opções de selecção de pesquisa ('TopSearch')!");
    return false;
}

return true;
}
```

and it´s giving me an "`Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object required`".

I can´t seem to figure out what i am doing wrong.

Comment: where is ddlTopSearch in html code??post ur full html code

Comment: you need to get ClientId and not the real id of the dropdown as it will be different always until so specify it explicitly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is usually appears when the `getElementById` is return null on the parametre, and you then try to use that parameter.

For example on this line, you probably did not find the `ddlTopSearch`

```
var dT=document.getElementById("ddlTopSearch").value;
```

because asp.net render it on page diferently, to get it correct/rendered ID use the `ClientID` as:

```
var dT=document.getElementById("<%=ddlTopSearch.ClientID%>").value;
```

The same with the rest ids.

Also, I must note here that the Drop Down List did not get the `value` as the rest of input controls. To get the value you must use this javascript code:

```
var e = document.getElementById("<%=ddlTopSearch.ClientID%>");
var sTopSearchValue = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
```

reference:
[Get selected value in dropdown list using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/how-to-get-the-selected-value-of-dropdownlist-using-javascript)

Comment: Yes, the exception was triggered on that line. I will try it. Thanks. Why ClientID?

Comment: @bruno Why ClientID, because this is the one that return the id as is render on html by asp.net. Look also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5763557/accessing-control-client-name-and-not-id-in-asp-net/5763632#5763632

Comment: @bruno Still you have nulls on your parametres. On which line you get that ?

Comment: If i use var dT=document.getElementById("<%=ddlTopSearch.ClientID%>").value; it gives me the error. If i use var dT=document.getElementById("<%=ddlTopSearch.ClientID%>"); it gives me null.

Comment: Like u said, i must have null parametres. I´m going to check it.

Comment: @bruno I have update the answer, on `select`, dropdownlist control the value must be get by this way http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/how-to-get-the-selected-value-of-dropdownlist-using-javascript

Answer (score -1):

Please provide the more details

If you are using the master page in your .aspx page then you should know that the control id is changed at run time.

I think in your case the problem is due to the wrong control id.

[Click here](http://blog.mdsohelrana.com/2008/06/12/an-important-issue-while-using-master-page-id-changed-of-the-controls/) for more information regarding control id changing due to master page.

Comment: I´m using a MasterPage and the id is dynamically changing.

Comment: then you can use this :document.getElementById("%=ddlTopSearch.ClientID %>").value;