# Why I can't get selected file on server side?

Tags: asp.net

I have this asp code:

```
        <asp:Panel runat="server">  
            <div class="row2">
            <input type="file" accept="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet, application/vnd.ms-excel" id="fileSelect" name="fileSelect" runat="server" />
            <asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" Text="load" OnClick="btnUpload_Click2" CausesValidation="False" />
            </div>
        </asp:Panel>
```

Here the generated HTML code on the browser:

```
<div class="row2">               
            <input name="ctl00$ContentPlace$fileSelect" type="file" id="ctl00_ContentPlace_fileSelect" accept="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet, application/vnd.ms-excel">
            <input type="submit" name="ctl00$ContentPlace$btnUpload" value="load" id="ctl00_ContentPlace_btnUpload">
        </div>
</div>
```

Here the code behind:

```
    protected void btnUpload_Click2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpPostedFile file = Request.Files["fileSelect"];                     
    }
```

After I select a file with help of input file element the btnUpload is pressed the code behind fired but I always get file value null.

If I change this row:

```
HttpPostedFile file = Request.Files["fileSelect"];
```

To this row:

```
HttpPostedFile file = Request.Files["ctl00$ContentPlace$fileSelect"];
```

I get the selected file in file variable on the server.

So my question is why I can't get file if I use this row:

```
HttpPostedFile file = Request.Files["fileSelect"];
```

Comment: If you inspect the resulting HTML on the client side, what is the value of the name attribute on your file upload element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input control that runs at **server side, change their id**, and to get the name that is posted you need to use the `UniqueID` as

```
HttpPostedFile file = Request.Files[fileSelect.UniqueID];
```

where in your case the `fileSelect.UniqueID` is return `"ctl00$ContentPlace$fileSelect"` that is the `nane` rendered control on the html, the one that used on post.

you can see also [Accessing control client name and not ID in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5763557/accessing-control-client-name-and-not-id-in-asp-net/5763632#5763632)

### How to use what you type

To use that line

```
HttpPostedFile file = Request.Files["fileSelect"];
```

just remove the `runat="server"` from your input control.