# hiding the link buttons when user leaves the text box

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a text box and two link buttons on my web page. When I put some value on the text box, based on that value and also as soon as I leave the textbox. I want to hide or make the link button invisible.

```
<asp:textBox id="textBox1" runat="server">
 <asp:linkButton id="link1" runat="server">
 <asp:linkButton id="link2" runar="server">
```

when the user enter value "X" in the textbox, I want to hide Link1 and Link2 otherwise I want  Link1 and Link2 to be visible.

here is my code and it is not working:

```
function HidePick(selectObj) {    
       if (selectObj.value.toUpperCase() == "D9") {
        document.getElementById("LINK1").style.display = 'none';
    }
}

  <td><asp:TextBox ID="TXTTest1" runat="server" CssClass="cssTest" Width="30" onmouseout="javascript:HidePick(this);"
```

With error message:

> "JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'style' of undefined
>   or null reference

Comment: why are you not using jquery? ... $("#link1").hide() or .toggle() https://api.jquery.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that kind of DOM manipulation, it is easy with jQuery.

JS Fiddle - [https://jsfiddle.net/p8pm6r5r](https://jsfiddle.net/p8pm6r5r/)

```
<asp:TextBox ID="textBox1" runat="server" />
<asp:LinkButton ID="link1" runat="server" Text="Button1" />
<asp:LinkButton ID="link2" runat="server" Text="Button2" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {
        $("#<%= textBox1.ClientID %>").blur(function () {
            if ($(this).val() === "X") {
                $("#<%= link1.ClientID %>").hide();
                $("#<%= link2.ClientID %>").hide();
            }
        });
    })
</script>
```

Comment: It did not ask for jQuery, neither have tag with jQuery on it.

Comment: It was tagged **ASP.Net**. It not uncommon to see **jQuery** in ASP.Net application these days. You just give him a fish, but I show him how to fish.

Comment: Still stands, not ask for jQuery solution.

Answer (score 0):

In asp.net the final render id may change on page, so on javascript you need to use the `.ClientID` of control... you code must be as:

```
document.getElementById("<%=link1.ClientID%>").style.display = 'none';
```

Related: [Accessing control client name and not ID in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5763557/accessing-control-client-name-and-not-id-in-asp-net/5763632#5763632)

Answer (score 0):

```
 <asp:textBox id="textBox1" runat="server">
<asp:LinkButton ID="link1" runat="server" Text="Button1" />
<asp:LinkButton ID="link2" runat="server" Text="Button2" />
```

Assuming you don't want to use jQuery or any library;
At the end of your htmls in .aspx page add a script tag to bind the button to **mouseleave** or **mouseout** events. Just to make sure your textbox1's id is static (the way it is in your source), once your page is rendered on the browser check for your textbox1 and see if it has still the same id if not then copy that id and replace in the below event binder line of javascript code from textbox1 to (whatever_textbox1). Same step for your link ids too.

```
document.getElementById("textBox1").addEventListener("mouseout",HidePick,false);
    function HidePick(e){
        if (e.target.value.toUpperCase() == "D9")
             document.getElementById("LINK1").style.display = 'none';    
    }
```