# How to use runat = "server" in input tag?

Tags: html, asp.net

I'm writing in asp.net. When I add `runat="server"` property to my input tag, its value is null. When I remove `runat="server"` it works correctly. Who knows the reason?

I want change its property from code behind, that's why I wrote `runat="server"`. However, the value is null.

```
protected void btnSaveChanges_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string current_id = Session["Current_user"].ToString(); 
    string a = Request.Form["newusername"]; 
    string b = Request.Form["newpassword"]; 
    string c = Request.Form["rewpassword"];
}
```

Code for control:

```
<input type="text" name="newusername" placeholder="Enter Username" required="required" runat="server"/>
```

Comment: Its value is null but exactly when ? can you please provide some code where its value is coming as null.

Comment: protected void btnSaveChanges_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string current_id = Session["Current_user"].ToString();
            string a = Request.Form["newusername"];
            string b = Request.Form["newpassword"];
            string c = Request.Form["rewpassword"];}

Comment: <input type="text" name="newusername" placeholder="Enter Username" required="required" runat="server"/>

Comment: `runat="server"` indicates that the input will exist in server-side code, not using `Request.Form` anymore. If you want to use its value just do `newusername.Text`, assumed you give `id="newusername"` attribute.

Comment: its value isn't null. But I add  `runat = "server"` its value returns null.

Comment: Thanks, @TetsuyaYamamoto it works.But it has not Text property.`newusername.Value` works

Comment: @fico - when you have updates to your question, please [edit] it into your question. Especially when it contains code as that is hard to format or read in a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add `runat="server"` and make the simple HTML control to asp.net HTML control, then asp.net renders the `id` and the `name` of that control in a manner that does not conflict with other asp.net controls on the same page.

So change the input to: (note now I add `id`, and remove the `name`!)

```
<input type="text" id="newusername" placeholder="Enter Username" required="required" runat="server"/>
```

and get the value using the post like this:

```
Request.Form[newusername.UniqueID]
```

or using the value:

```
newusername.value
```

other links to consider:
[Accessing control client name and not ID in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5763557/accessing-control-client-name-and-not-id-in-asp-net/5763632#5763632)

Answer (score 0):

Use **newusername.Value** to access the value of the control in your server side function.

Like

```
protected void btnSaveChanges_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string current_id = Session["Current_user"].ToString();
        string a = newusername.Value;
        string b = newpassword.Value;
        string c = rewpassword.Value;
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

You can't change an HTML control's properties using c# server side code. But you can do that using several other methods -

**Method 1**
you can use plain javascript or jquery to alter the HTML DOM element.

**Method 2**
you can create the HTML elements you want dynamically using HtmlGenericControl.

```
HtmlGenericControl username = new HtmlGenericControl("input");
username.attr("type", "text");
username.attr("name", "newusername");
```

And then you can append the controls into some div, like,

Front-End HTML code where you will add your dynamic controls-

```
<div id="dynaHtml" runat="server"></div>
```

Now, you can use that div to add your dynamic controls to page -

```
dynaHtml.Controls.Add(username);
```