# Popup Calendar problem - not working when change to addListener

Tags: asp.net

I'm having a problem putting Matt's Calendar Popup when using it for addEventListener.  I'm doing it on ASP.net VB.

This aspx code works but only for IE

```
<script language="JavaScript" src="/Content/Scripts/CalendarPopup.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
            var cal = new CalendarPopup();
    </script>

<asp:TextBox ID="txtRequestDate" runat="server" MaxLength="10" Style="width: 70px; height: 15px;
                            border: 1px solid silver;"></asp:TextBox>

<a href="#" onclick="cal.select(document.forms['frmMain'].txtRequestDate,'aFrom','dd/MM/yyyy'); return false;"
                            name="aFrom" id="aFrom">Select</a>
```

But when I change it to addEventListener (so that it will work on Chrome)

Popup.js

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    document.getElementById("selCalendar").addEventListener("click", showCalendar, false);
});


function showCalendar() {
    var cal = new CalendarPopup();
    //alert("After CalendarPopup");
    cal.select(window.document.forms['frmMain'].txtRequestDate,'aFrom','dd/MM/yyyy'); return false;
}
```

aspx code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Content/Scripts/Popup.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Content/Scripts/CalendarPopup.js"></script>

<a href="#" id="selCalendar">Select</a></td>
```

Please help to fix this problem as I'm doing trying to do this for 2 days now.   Thanks

Link of Matt Kruse's CalendarPopup.js ==> http://forge.ipsl.jussieu.fr/epoll/browser/trunk/root/static/js/CalendarPopup.js?rev=61

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this might not help?

If you just drop in a plane jane text box, and choose this:

Then without any code then you get this:

So, as a FYI, there is a nice date picker built in.

```
   <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" TextMode="DateTimeLocal" Width="188px"></asp:TextBox>
```

So if you set txt mode, then you get this:

[image]

And if text mode = date, then this:

[image]

Now, this may or may not help you, but a nice date picker is built in - and no code or add-ins is required.

Answer (score 0):

For start one basic bug is that you do not get the correct id from your textbox

on the javascript code, replace the `txtRequestDate` with
`<%=txtRequestDate.ClientID%>`

related : [Accessing control client name and not ID in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5763557/accessing-control-client-name-and-not-id-in-asp-net/5763632#5763632)

Comment: Thanks for replying, Aristos but...

I tried both codes inside Popup.js.  Both didn't work

`cal.select(window.document.forms['frmMain'].txtRequestDate.UniqueID,'aFrom','dd/MM/yyyy'); return false;
}`

and

`cal.select(window.document.forms['frmMain'].<%=txtRequestDate.ClientID%>,'aFrom','dd/MM/yyyy'); return false;`

Comment: @Tracer1 can you open please the debugger on the browser to see what javascript error do you get ? and go from there