# Jquery on change function not working with asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have tried with the following code with live, change function. but not working

live function is given below,

```
$(function () {
            $('#txt_ToDate').live('change', function (e) {
            alert("hai");
            var txt_FromDate = document.getElementById('txt_FromDate');
            var txt_ToDate = document.getElementById('txt_ToDate');
            txt_ToDate.value = txt_FromDate.value;
        });
        });
```

Change function is given below.

```
$(function () {
            $('#txt_ToDate').change(function () {
            alert("hai");
            var txt_FromDate = document.getElementById('txt_FromDate');
            var txt_ToDate = document.getElementById('txt_ToDate');
            txt_ToDate.value = txt_FromDate.value;
        });
```

but not hitting alert. how to fix this issue.

html code is given below,

```
<td style="text-align: left;" class="auto-style1">
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txt_FromDate" runat="server" class="inputCalendar2_font14" Width="105px"
                                                    onfocus="showCalendarControl(this);" onkeypress="return false;" onpaste="return false;"
                                                    CssClass="inputCalendar2_font14"></asp:TextBox>
                                                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                              <asp:TextBox ID="txt_ToDate" runat="server" class="inputCalendar2_font14" Width="105px" OnTextChanged="txt_ToDate_TextChanged"
                                                  onfocus="showCalendarControl(this);" onkeypress="return false;" onpaste="return false;"
                                                  CssClass="inputCalendar2_font14"></asp:TextBox>

                                            </td>
```

Reference is given below,

```
<script src="../jScript/BrowserCompatibility.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../jScript/jquery-1.4.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../calenderCtr/CalendarControl.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>
    <link href="../calenderCtr/CalendarControl.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="../jScript/Validator.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>
    <link href="../style/dsi_mig.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `.change` function, Use `.on('change')` like this:

```
    $(function () {
        $('#txt_ToDate').on('change', function () {
        alert("hai");
        var txt_FromDate = document.getElementById('txt_FromDate');
        var txt_ToDate = document.getElementById('txt_ToDate');
        txt_ToDate.value = txt_FromDate.value;
    });
```

the usage of  on change in jquery is different in different versions.

Comment: Thank you for the response. i have tried your answer. but it is not working

Comment: i am using calender in the text box.

Comment: can you share your html code as well?

Comment: html code added in the question

Comment: my actual requirement is when i choose date in from text box(from date) the same date effect in to text box(to date)

Answer (score 0):

When asp.net renders the `asp:TextBox` you may not have the `txt_ToDate` as id.

To get the rendered ID on page you must use the `ClientID` as

```
$(function () {
            $('#<%=txt_ToDate.ClientID%>').change(function () {
            alert("hai");
            var txt_FromDate = document.getElementById('txt_FromDate');
            var txt_ToDate = document.getElementById('txt_ToDate');
            txt_ToDate.value = txt_FromDate.value;
        });
```

this is the main change `$('#<%=txt_ToDate.ClientID%>')`

You can also read this answer: [Accessing control client name and not ID in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5763557/accessing-control-client-name-and-not-id-in-asp-net/5763632#5763632)